# Where is DNS cache located on Windows 8.1?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, dns, cache, ipconfig

I'm reading about DNS cache and particularly about `ipconfig /flushdns` command. There are many resources out there - QA, blogs, sites - that explain what is DNS cache but none of them say ***where*** DNS cache is located on my Windows 8.1 machine. If I get it right, it should be a file with mappings, something like the following:

```
example.com 123.123.123.123
foo.net 123.123.0.0
```

Before I run `ipconfig /flushdns`, I want to see that DNS cache file. Where can I find it on my machine?

Comment: Probably in-memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the DNS cache, recent versions of Microsoft Windows support `IPConfig /displaydns`

(I don't think Windows 98 supported it; neither did Win98 support `ipconfig /flushdns`.  I would guess both options got added to the same version of Microsoft Windows.)

This is the typical/easy way to view such information.

I'm not offhand sure what file this information is stored in.  I'm pretty sure that it doesn't use the HOSTS-like format that you show, because I'm sure it also keeps track of expiration time.  Using Process Explorer may help to find out what file gets accessed when using `IPConfig/displaydns`.

Comment: There _is_ no "cache file" – the cache is kept in memory only. It is maintained by the "DNS Client" service (internally named `Dnscache`), therefore the cache data would be somewhere inside one of the `svchost.exe` processes.

Answer (score 4):

Just to back up what others have said, using `Process Hacker` to search for strings within `svchost.exe` you can see the entries stored in memory. Eg.

[image]

A far less useful output than simply using `ipconfig /displaydns` (Which you can always output to a file using `ipconfig /displaydns>output.txt` if you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

The cache may be kept in memory, and the local dns service may not keep a cache file, but there is a little more to it.

My ipconfig /displaydns was preserving entries between reboots for me. It must be kept on disk somewhere.

I had a dns problem today and when checking with an old VM, I discovered some really old entries in my local dnscache. These were entries from my old company and at first I thought maybe they were hacking in or I was still connected somehow to their network. But they also contained some of my own entries from VMs from quite awhile ago.

ipconfig /flushdns would not wipe the entries. I tried stopping and restarting the dns service. Did not help. I disconnected my router from the Internet and the entries still remained. Then I remembered that that VM used to be a domain controller and dns server from long ago so I suspected something didn't get uninstalled correctly.

I used procman.exe and isolated the instance of svchost.exe that responded to ping requests. On a ping, it opened the hosts file and nothing else. Stupid me, I should have checked the hosts file before starting all this. All the old entries were in the hosts file. Once they were wiped there, they did not show up in ipconfig /displaydns.

When the local dns service is stopped and restarted, existing entries are wiped, so that tends to confirm they are only kept in cache memory. But yes, persistent ipconfig dns entries used by ping via the local dns are located in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.

Hope this helps anyone else trying to troubleshoot this.